# Best practice to check and redirect to home or loginscreen on android

Tags: android, android-intent, authentication, android-activity, user-experience

For example when you open facebook for android if you havent session automatically sends you to loginscreen. There are too many ways to do that. In your experience. What is the better practice to recognize the user state and redirect to the correct activity??

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this case is not to send the user to a different activity but rather just show a Log-in `DialogFragment` that the user can use to log in and hence removing the overhead from your end to keep track of the last activity the user was on. Just add this Login `DialogFragment`, authenticate the user and dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

i have same scenario in my app, as user **d3m0li5h3r** suggested ,i also used fragments,which is a good practice to avid overhead.Coming back to your question,you  can use shared preferences ,in which you can set a flag to make sure whether user is already logged in or logged out,based on the flag you can load the fragment(log-in fragment or any other fragment) accordingly 
refer [this](http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html) link to understand  shared preference